# VS Code - highlight some variables with TextMate

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, textmate, tmlanguage

VS Code 1.15 added support for TextMate grammar rules. I want to highlight some variables in JavaScript with these rules: self, me. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe soon you will be gain full control about how you highlight anything: This is WIP: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Semantic-Highlighting-Overview

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

I'm assuming you're referring to the [new `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_15#_user-definable-syntax-highlighting-colors). This setting only allows you to change the colors associated with specific scopes that the TextMate grammar *already* defines. `self` and `me` are not treated specially by the JS gramar, they use the same `variable.other.readwrite.js` scope as any other variable:

[image]

Contrast this with the `this` keyword: It has its own unique `variable.language.this.js` scope, so we could use the setting to color `this` red:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "variable.language.this.js",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: So, I did read docs right. I don't need highlighting this keyword, only specific variables. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, the `this` customization was just a counter-example to show what you _can_ do with `tokenColorCustomizations`.

Comment: @Gama11 -- How did you get that popup showing language, token type, etc.?

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+P; Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes

Comment: But is there a way to add new tokens to an existing syntax highlight scheme?

Answer (score 4):

As @Gama11 said, you can't do it with the editor.tokenColorCustomizations but you could do it with the extension [TODO Highlight](https://github.com/wayou/vscode-todo-highlight).  It is not the intended use but it would easily work for what you want.  The only problem being that 'self' and 'me' would be highlighted if they appeared within any text as well with a default implementation, but that could be fixed using a regexp with word boundaries.  Here is a sample implementation:

```
"todohighlight.keywords": [
    "DEBUG:",
    "REVIEW:",
    {
        "text": "NOTE:",
        "color": "#ff0000",
        "backgroundColor": "yellow",
        "overviewRulerColor": "grey"
    },
    {
        "text": "HACK:",
        "color": "#000",
        "isWholeLine": false
    },
    {
        "text": "TODO:",
        "color": "red",
        "borderRadius":"0px",
        "backgroundColor": "rgba(0,0,0,.2)"
    }
],
```

You could just replace with your 'self' and 'me'.  I use an interesting pattern:

```
  //  highlight `TODO:`,`FIXME:` and 'HACK:' and content between parentheses

  // "todohighlight.keywordsPattern": "((\\s\\sTODO\\s*:\\s{0,5})|(\\s\\sFIXME\\s*:\\s{0,5})|(\\s\\sHACK\\s*:\\s{0,5}))(\\(.*\\)\\s)*",
```

It highlights TODO:, FIXME: and HACK: if they are preceded by some spaces as well as any content that follows that is in parens.

But I don't see why this extension couldn't be used to highlight any particular text you want but you'll probably want to include a space before and maybe after 'me' and 'self' in case they may also appear embedded within other text such as 'varmetoo'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I aware of this extension and was interested if this can be done with TextMate in the new VSCode.