# VSCode, Javascript - change syntax color for data types

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, types, syntax

What is the scope selector for changing the syntax color of data types (Number, String, Boolean) with textMateRules?

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
 "[Monokai Pro (Filter Spectrum)]": {
   "textMateRules": [
     {
       "scope": ["???"],
       "settings": {
         "foreground": "#ff6188"
       }
     }
   ]
 }
```

NOTE: I dont want to change theme. Im trying to only change the color of data types from white [current setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWCu2.png) to another color, like in [wanted setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juQnM.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TextMate scope you're looking for is `variable.other.readwrite.js`, so:

```json
"[Monokai Pro (Filter Spectrum)]": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": ["variable.other.readwrite.js"],
      "settings": {
        "foreground": "#ff6188"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: Preview]

### How to find the TextMate Scope

1. Open Command Palette and search for "Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes"
2. Place your mouse caret on top of the code you wish to change its color
3. The TextMate scope you're looking for is usually the first line of "textmate scopes"

[image: textmate scope preview]

Comment: Thanks. Inspecting scopes is a great tip I'll take with me. This does however change more than just data types. Do you know if it's possible to target words? Like "String" or "thisWordShouldBeGreen"?

Comment: Sorry I don't know a method to do that. Judging from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45631153/11067496), I guess that is not possible

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your color theme in VS Code. For example the color theme you're using is `Monokai`. The required theme seems to be `Dark ++ italic`.

## Step 1

- So to change your theme first head on to extensions tab and search for `Dark++ Italic`  and install it. The sample of Dark++ Italic
  is [image]

## Step 2

- Hit ctrl K + ctrl T and Select Dark++ Italic.

Comment: I see that my question was poorly defined. I updated the post to better describe what Im trying to do. Thanks for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 0):

Bottom left of your screen select settings then go to Color Theme

[image]

Then, Select Dark+ (default Theme)

[image]

Comment: I see that my question was poorly defined. I updated the post to better describe what Im trying to do. Thanks for taking the time to answer