# Color method header in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to color method header differently in VSCode?

By method header, I mean the lines containing the method name, parameters and return type. These can be spread across multiple lines depending on the language.

I am looking for this as a means to help focus on the method body when the method header spans across more than 2 lines in some programs written in languages like Rust.

Comment: use the TextMateScope of the parts of the line to change the colors

Answer (score 0):

Using TextMateScope rules, we can set the foreground color and font style (underline/bold/italics/strikethrough) of the method header. Here is an example that sets the fontStyle

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
       "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "meta.function.definition.rust",
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "bold underline"
            }
        }
       ]
    }
```

Since there is no way to color the background, this is the closest that I prefer.

Use vscode's scope inspector to find the relevant scope - https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector

---

Similar question: [VS Code - highlight some variables with TextMate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45631153/vs-code-highlight-some-variables-with-textmate)

Thanks to @rioV8 for the recommendation in the comment.

---

I tried the semanticTokenColorCustomizations, but it does not allow textMateRules. The following will color all method names used  in declaration with orange color. Method calls are not affected.

```
    "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
        "enabled": true,
        "rules": {
            "method.declaration": {
                "foreground": "#FFA500"
            }
        },
    }
```

https://medium.com/@danromans/how-to-customize-semantic-token-colorization-with-visual-studio-code-ac3eab96141b